# What are these set operations, and why do they give different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, set, set-operations

I had seen this test question on Pluralsight:

Given these sets:

```
x = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
y = {'c', 'e', 'f'}
z = {'a', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
```

What is the value of `x | y ^ z`?

The expected answer is:

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
```

Combines the sets (automatically discarding duplicates), and orders them from lowest to greatest.

My questions are:

- What is this expression called?
- Why do I get 3 different results from 3 different Python versions?

---

Result on Python 3.7.5 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
{'c', 'h', 'f', 'd', 'b', 'i', 'g', 'a', 'e'}
```

Result on Python 2.17.17rc1 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h'])
```

Result on Python 3.7.2 on Windows 10:

```
{'a', 'd', 'h', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'e', 'c', 'i'}
```

Here is a repl of the same code I'm using for this:
https://repl.it/repls/RudeMoralWorkplace

I'd like to understand what happens behind the scenes with these expressions so I can debunk why I get different results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set operations you have mentioned are:

**`^` - [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) (XOR):**

> Return a new set with elements in either the set or other but not both.

**Example:** `{'1', '2', '3'} ^ {'2', '3', '4'} = {'1', '4'}`

**`|` - [union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) (OR):**

> Return a new set with elements from the set and all others.

**Example:** `{'1', '2', '3'} | {'2', '3', '4'} = {'1', '2', '3', '4'}`

There are also other set operations in python:

**`&` - [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) (AND):**

> Return a new set with elements common to the set and all others.

**Example:** `{'1', '2', '3'} & {'2', '3', '4'} = {'2', '3'}`

**`-` - [difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):**

> Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the others.

**Example:** `{'1', '2', '3'} - {'2', '3', '4'} = {'1'}`

The order of precedence for these operations is `-, &, ^, |`, so in your example, we first apply `^`:

```
>>> y^z
{'a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
```

And then `|`:

```
>>> x|{'a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
```

The different outputs you describe are actually the same set, as sets are not ordered.

```
>>> {'c', 'h', 'f', 'd', 'b', 'i', 'g', 'a', 'e'} == {'a', 'd', 'h', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'e', 'c', 'i'}
True
```

Any order shown in the string representation of a set is an implementation detail and should not be relied upon as it will vary unpredictably, as you have found.

Comment: Forgot to accept this answer, but thank you for the verbosity! The answer being `abcd` in order was a bit of a red herring here.